# OpenCV Java limit contours

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am using OpenCV in an Android application. I want the mobile application to automatically take a photo when a rectangle (something in the shape of a receipt for example) is in view. I am using Canny edge detection but when I am looking for contours, the array size is greater than 1500. Obviously it is not optimal to loop through all the contours and find the largest one so I was wondering is it possible to filter out the largest contour automatically through an api?

My code so far:

```
ArrayList contours;

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(final CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    // Clear contours array on each frame
    contours.clear();

    // Get Grayscale image
    final Mat gray = inputFrame.gray();

    // Canny edge detection 
    Imgproc.Canny(gray, gray, 300, 1000, 5, true);

    // New empty black matrix to store the edges captured
    Mat dest = new Mat();
    Core.add(dest, Scalar.all(0), dest);

    // Copy the edge data over to the empty black matrix
    gray.copyTo(dest);

    // Is there a way to filter the size of contours so that not everything is returned? Right now this function is returning a lot of contours (1500 +)
    Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, hirearchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    return dest;
}
```

**EDIT**
The user will be holding the phone and I want the application to automatically take a photo when the receipt is in view.
[Example receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG7Ef.jpg)

Comment: May be if  you provide some input images then some better technique than Canny could be suggested, As the canny is used to detect the edges it is not a wise idea to detect objects using canny results a there may be a lost of noise even after adjusting the params, So I would suggest You to go for use color segmentation as You know beforehand what color the recipt is going to be in, and adjust the thresholds of color limits a bit to counter the brightness variance in the input image

Comment: The receipt images are going to be black and white. I want a way for the camera to detect the receipt from the background and automatically take a photo of it.

Comment: And what if the person is holding bogus empty white paper, or there is some other white colored object in the background ?

Comment: This isn't a commercial product, just a project for me to learn about the opencv library. As long as the photo is taken automatically it is fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

I have covered the basic techniques you may use, in the following Python code, it won't be hard to translate the code in the language of your choice, java in this case. So the technique involves:

- Estimate the color of object you want to segment, which is white in your case, so safe limits for upper and lower bound can be approximated as:

  ```
  RECEIPT_LOWER_BOUND = np.array([200, 200, 200])
  RECEIPT_UPPER_BOUND = np.array([255, 255, 255])
  ```
- Apply some Blur to input image to make the color distribution smooth, which would reduce the smaller contours in future.

  ```
  img_blurred = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))
  ```
- Apply dilation to the binary image to remove the neighbouring smaller contours which surround your target largest contour

  ```
  kernel = np.ones((10, 10), dtype=np.uint8)
  mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel)
  ```
- Now find contours in the mask after applying above operations and filter out the contour on the basis of contourArea.

  ```
  im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(receipt_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
  largest_contour = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
  ```
- Finally you may apply some threshold over the area to verify if the input was really a ticket or not.

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# You may change the following ranges to define your own lower and upper BGR bounds.
RECEIPT_LOWER_BOUND = np.array([200, 200, 200])
RECEIPT_UPPER_BOUND = np.array([255, 255, 255])


def segment_receipt(img):
    # Blur the input image to reduce the noise which in-turn reduces the number of contours
    img_blurred = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))
    mask = cv2.inRange(img_blurred, RECEIPT_LOWER_BOUND, RECEIPT_UPPER_BOUND)

    # Also dilate the binary mask which further reduces the salt and pepper noise
    kernel = np.ones((10, 10), dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel)
    return mask


def get_largest_contour_rect(image):
    receipt_mask = segment_receipt(image)
    im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(receipt_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    print "Number of contours found :", len(contours)

    # Sorting the contours to get the largest one
    largest_contour = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))

    # Return the last contour in sorted list as the list is sorted in increasing order.
    return cv2.boundingRect(largest_contour)

image = cv2.imread("path/to/your/image.jpg")
rect = get_largest_contour_rect(image)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@J.Doe I am currently working on such a project and I have successfully being able to isolate the largest contour in the image after a whole lot of processing. The only part remaining is recognizing a rectangular contour and taking a picture.

```
mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Imgproc.Canny(mRgba,mCanny,50,200);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGray, mGray1, new Size(3, 3), 1);
    Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT,new Size(9,9));

    Imgproc.dilate(mGray1, mGray2, kernel);
    Imgproc.Canny(mGray2, mCanny, 50, 200);

    Imgproc.findContours(mCanny,contours,hierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_TREE,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    double maxVal = 0;
    int maxValIdx = 0;
    for(int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++){
        double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
        if(maxVal < contourArea)
        {
            maxVal = contourArea;
            maxValIdx = contourIdx;
        }
    }
    Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba,contours,maxValIdx,new Scalar(0,255,255),-1);
    return mRgba;
```

Be wary of the image names i changed them over different processes.